# Existing DB2 column reported as not being a column of the table

Tags: sql, db2, moodle, db2-luw

In a Moodle 2 install running on DB2, deleting a user is unsuccessful, returning an *error reading from database*:

> Debug info: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0206N "USERIDFROM" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-206
>   SELECT * FROM mdl_message WHERE useridfrom = ? ORDER BY timecreated
>   [array (
>   0 => '28521',
>   )]

The error description for [SQL0206N](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00206n.html) is clear, but `useridfrom` is a column of `mdl_message`:

```
$ db2 describe table mdl_message

                          Data type                     Column
Column name               schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
 ID                       SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No    
 USERIDFROM               SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No    
 USERIDTO                 SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No    
 SUBJECT                  SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    200     0 Yes   
 FULLMESSAGE              SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    200     0 Yes   
 FULLMESSAGEFORMAT        SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes   
 FULLMESSAGEHTML          SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    100     0 Yes   
 SMALLMESSAGE             SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    200     0 Yes   
 NOTIFICATION             SYSIBM    SMALLINT                     2     0 Yes   
 CONTEXTURL               SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    200     0 Yes   
 CONTEXTURLNAME           SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    200     0 Yes   
 TIMECREATED              SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No    

  12 record(s) selected.
```

What else could cause this error?

Comment: From the error message you're getting, it is unclear what the WHERE clause you're using is. Did you forget to put one in?

Comment: That is a weird error, is there trigger on the table or something?  Or is there some way to turn case-sensitivity on?  And not accidently a `1` (one) or `l` (ell) or similar?    Beyond that, I'm assuming `TIMECREATED` is a count of milli(or nano) seconds since the epoch, in UTC - to get around the fact that DB2 doesn't store the timezone information in timestamps?

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like you passed a question mark to DB2 for USERIDFROM instead of a big integer.

Comment: Even from CLI, a simple `$ db2 "select * from  mdl_message where USERIDFROM = 28251"` returns `SQL0206N  "USERIDFROM" is not valid in the context where it is used.    
SQLSTATE=42703`

Comment: @X-Zero and no, I don't have any triggers on the table.

Comment: Can you try "select USERIDFROM from mdl_message fetch first 1 rows only" ?

Comment: @Leons `$ db2 "select USERIDFROM from mdl_message fetch first 1 rows only"` returns 
`SQL0206N  "USERIDFROM" is not valid in the context where it is used.    
SQLSTATE=42703`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that the column name somehow got a space in it. You can use this query to find out if there's any trailing blank space:

```
db2 "select '<' || name || '>' from sysibm.syscolumns where tbname = 'MDL_MESSAGE'"
```

Comment: One quick question, when i am checking columns from "sysibm.syscolumns" it is giving me bunch of columns but i cannot see that column when i do "select* from t_name", it is subset of the columns shown in above sysibm columns. Can you pleas help me understand why there is variation in the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are connecting as the same user from command line and CLI. There might be a case where in the same table is present in different schema and you are seeing description of different table but accessing the other one.